# Saving an XML document changes single quotes to double quotes

Tags: xml, delphi, xpath, delphi-xe2

I have an XML file that I need to read in Delphi XE2, use XPath to find some nodes, then manipulate those nodes. The input XML file uses single quotes around attribute values. When I call SaveToFile, the XML file now has double quotes instead of single quotes around attribute values. I know in the XML spec that single vs double quotes doesn't matter, as long as they are matching. However this causes two issues: 1) The third-party program reading the XML file doesn't like the double quotes and 2) Diffs are messy to read.

Is there a way to prevent the single quotes from changing to double quotes when I call SaveToFile?

Although experienced in Delphi, I am new to using Delphi to manipulate XML so I may be way off on the objects I chose to use. It's cobbled together from a few examples I was able to find online.

```
var doc: IXMLDocument;
  Node : IDOMNode;
  Sel: IDOMNodeSelect;
  List : IDOMNodeList;
  j : Integer;
begin
  doc := TXMLDocument.Create(Application);
  doc.LoadFromFile('somefile.xml'); //Input file uses single quotes around    attribute values
  doc.active := True;
  Sel := doc.DOMDocument as IDomNodeSelect;
  List := Sel.selectNodes('//column[not(@hidden=''true'') and @caption]');
  for j := 0 to List[i].childNodes.length-1 do
    List[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue := 'foo';

  doc.SaveToFile('somefile2.xml'); //This is a copy to compare against the original
  //Output file has double quotes around attribute values
end;
```

Comments and suggestions for different objects to use with XML and XPath in Delphi are appreciated too. The code seems too cobbled together to me.

Comment: "*Is there a way to prevent the single quotes from changing to double quotes when I call SaveToFile?*" - not a standard way, no.  The XML standard may allow both types of quotes when parsing, but double-quotes are the de-facto standard when saving. You will have to look at the capabilities of the underlying DOM engine to see if it exposes any option to change the quote character used.

Comment: You need to fix the program that reads the xml

Comment: If the diffs are messy to read, then I expect you're not using an XML-aware diffing tool.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the above comments are technically correct: the "third-party program reading the XML file" is not, in fact, compliant with the XML spec, and one could use an XML-aware `diff` to avoid the `diff` problem.  But I suspect that the OP has no ability to complain usefully and does not possess the relevant `diff`.

I see two reasonable work-arounds, both involving scripts.

The first suggestion is a hack.  Just run *your* XML output through `sed -e s/"/'/g` before doing the `diff`.  The point is that there can be no `"` marks in valid XML other than those around attribute values, so assuming the program that *saves* the XML is compliant this should be fine.

The second suggestion is to run the *original* XML through something like `readxml | savexml`, using your XML program, before doing the `diff`, again relying on the XML program at your end doing its job correctly.